# What way let website administrators enter control panel?

Tags: php, web, admin

I have a website made in PHP, MySQL and stuff. I am using url rewrites in my website so an administrator needs to go to `http://{website}.com/admin/` and enter his/her username and password there to get to control panel where he/she updates the most of website, including language files, etc.

Now I'm wondering in what way should I let this website administrators access `http://{website}.com/admin`.

Should they really go to that link? `/admin`? Because I have heard this is not the most recommended way and I think most of today's websites manage to do this in different way? Some specially created desktop app? Other?

Please let me know what is really the most recommended way to do this.

Comment: To start with, why don't you change /admin to something less predictable?

Comment: If you have a secured login there's no problem with it being there. The biggest problem is with bots trying to login, but you should blacklist their IPs, for example, after 3 failed login attempts or something like that.

Comment: It's much easier to change the default admin to something else, than to effectively blacklist bot IP's. Blacklisting IP's creates another level of problems for the site and limiting login attempts does not prevent distributed hacking efforts.

Comment: I beg to differ that most today's websites do this in a different way.. I would argue, that most websites with a vendor cms like "Joomla" use the standard routing. (http://ace.nd.edu/administrator/). But - what do I know (He/She knows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not recommended because it is most obvious. Still, if your security is there it is rather irrelevant what URL it would be. By not using `/admin` (but instead i.e. `/a32mTT`) you filter out some automated attempts, but that's mostly it. I'd not consider this "security" at all. From other hand, your users/admins may find problematic memorizing `/a32mTT` instead of `/admin`. And finally, if your security sucks, then once your URL leak you might get toasted quickly, so focus on real security first :)

Comment: Yes, I think I accept ur answer. My security is okay I think, I recently migrated this website from mysql to mysqli and in other security issues I think website is doing okay. I wonder how do some professional, more developed websites handle this admin issue..

Comment: best yet is to host the admin stuff on a completely unrelated domain and/or hostname. your average script kiddie will directly try example.com/admin, but would never think to try on not-the-example-com-admin-panel.com site

Comment: The correct answer is already posted. About a desktop app, all it does is to send a security key through HTTPS POST to a specific link and that link first checks for that security key. It's another layer of pseudo-security but it just makes it harder and harder for newbies to get into your website.

Answer (score 2):

The way you want to access the site as a admin is mostly used , cms i.e. content management sites are the best example for that, But  as you have mentioned that you are using Php,mysql, so i will advice you to use  a framework like yii,joomla,wordpress etc,  which helps the admin to manage site from the remote location as well like http://www.foo.com/admin.php.  or similar one, I recommend you yii, wordpress both are opensource i.e. free, for yii you must know MVC i.e Model View Controller.
Just google yii or wordpress Go to their site download the file mostly in. Zip format extract in htdocs folder  if using Wamp, For more tutorials use their forum or various tutorials are available on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Thats big question. Probably for secure enhancement better use something else than admin. I know some using subdomains like cms.website.com. But again if you really concerned about security that's should not be sufficient.